# Set Intermediate Directory in C# Project

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In VS 2008, is there a way to set the intermediate directory (where the .obj files go, not the final targets) in a C# project?

Comment: +1 for good question. I've tried to do the same thing for the same reasons (not to pollute source directory with compiler output) and failed (without a security warning dialog -- but that's not acceptable for me).

Comment: Anybody knows if this situation changed in Visual Studio 2010/.NET4...?

Comment: MSVS 2019 has a setting but intermediate files, albeit for C++ (.exp, .iobj, .ipdb, lib and .pdb), still appear in the output dir.

Answer (score 7):

You need to override BaseIntermediateOutputPath msbuild var, more about it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/8095ddf9-86e1-41a6-b788-151346ad2dfa).

Comment: That does work for the most part but I was looking for a way to set it in each project so building from the IDE would not pollute the source folder. However, setting BaseIntermediateOutputPath in the project triggers a security warning. Alas, this does not seem possible. sigh...

Comment: The security warning is there to notify you that something out of the ordinary has happen, you can mute the warning, and you won't see it again until you change the something else.

Comment: there is nothing out of the ordinary about customizing intermediate output location. Visual Studio happily accepts C++ projects customizing intermediate files location (via IntDir property) without a security warning dialog, yet it does throw a tantrum when the same is done in C# project.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this using Visual Studio Express 2013; I forget which version of VS introduced MSBuild, and I can't say for sure that this will work for any other version.  But here goes:

In `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` are subdirectories corresponding to .NET versions;  With VSX2013 on my system the folder of interest is `v4.0.30319`.  (That's the .NET version used by MSBuild, not the one I'm targeting.)  Within this folder are `.targets` files, which are collections of MSBuild rules.

Near the beginning of `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` are some rules that will import more rules files.  The third of these import statements imports from the file named by the build variable `CustomBeforeMicrosoftCSharpTargets`.  You might be able to figure out the name of this by reading the rules, but it's easier to add a custom build step of

```
echo $(CustomBeforeMicrosoftCSharpTargets)
```

Build and look at the output.  In my case, the full path was

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\v12.0\Custom.Before.Microsoft.CSharp.targets
```

NOTE: in my case, there was already a folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0` but not `v12.0`.

So (as admin) I created the folder and placed a `Custom.Before.Microsoft.CSharp.targets` file that looks like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\Build\$(MSBuildProjectName)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

NOTE: `$(ProjectName)` does not work, use `$(MSBuildProjectName)`.

When I built, the OBJs were placed under a Build directory under the solution, not under the project, in a subdirectory with the typical naming convention: `Debug` or `Release` or `x86\Debug` or `x64\Release`.

This did not work exactly as desired: I really wanted to place these in `%TEMP%` but the variable was not expanded, so I ended up with a build folder under the project called `%TEMP%`.  Placing the expanded path in the rule worked just fine, but other subfolders of `%APPDATA%` failed due to permissions issues.

I assume this can be used to configure any of those variables; reading the default `.TARGETS` files is a chore but there are some useful comments therein.

Comment: Just a further note: the above approach works for VS CE 2017. `CustomBeforeMicrosoftCSharpTargets` has a value of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\v15.0`, and again I had to create the `v15.0` folder; no changes required to the XML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. However, you can copy your executables, dlls, whatever, to another folder in a post-build event. (Build Events tab in Project Properties)